# Noncommutative localization of a ring: complete construction

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, localization, noncommutative-rings, noncommutative-algebra

I've been looking for the following construction in the literature, but I've only been able to find (very) partial proofs or proofs of special cases.

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring and $S$ a multiplicative subset (i.e., $1 \in S$ and if $a, b \in S$ then $ab \in S$, the set $S$ can in particular **contain zero-divisors**).

It is known that the localization $RS^{-1}$ exists if :

1. for $a \in R$ and $s \in S$, there exist $b \in R$ and $t \in S$ such that $at = sb$,
2. if $sa = 0$ for $s \in S$ and $a \in R$, then there exists $t \in S$ such that $at = 0$.

Many sources give the complete construction in the simpler case where the set $S$ only contains regular elements (i.e. non-zero divisors).

The general case is presented in (amongst others) : *Rings of Quotients : An Introduction to Methods of Ring Theory* by Bo Stenström (Prop. 1.4, Chap. II, p.51) or in *Algebra, Volume 3* by P. M. Cohn (Thm. 1.3, Chap. 9, p. 350) but in both cases large parts of the proof are omitted.

Does anyone know where I can find the complete construction? In particular, the fact that the multiplication is well-defined (i.e., does not depend on the representing objects of the classes)?

Answer (score 15):

The localization $RS^{-1}$ *always* exists due to abstract nonsense: The subfunctor of $\hom(R,-)$ of homomorphisms mapping $S$ to units is continuous and the solution set condition is satisfied, so by Freyd's criterion for representability the subfunctor is actually representable. Specifically, it consists of elements of the form $r_1 s_1^{-1} r_2 s_2^{-1} \dotsc$, and sums of elements of this form. However, for practical uses, one wants elements of the form $r s^{-1}$ (or $s^{-1} r$, or both options) and an easy condition for equality of such fractions (some people put this into the definition of the localization, but this is artificial). This is contained in the **Ore condition**. You can find this everywhere (just google for "Ore condition"), for example in "An Introduction to Noncommutative Noetherian Rings" by K. R. Goodearl, Robert B. Warfield, Chapter 6.

Comment: If you don't have Ore conditions, how do you add?

Comment: Thanks for the link! But in chapter 6, Goodearl & Warfield only treat the case where the set S contains no zero-divisor.
I am looking the more general case where S can contain zero-divisors as well.

Answer (score 10):

If I remember well, the second chapter of

> J. C. McConnell, J. C. Robson. **Noncommutative Noetherian rings**, vol. 30
>   of Graduate Studies in Mathematics (American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2001)

contains a rather detailled proof of the Ore's theorem.

**Edit:** I just checked it on [Google books](http://books.google.ch/books?hl=en&lr=&id=c3fWk8LoSvgC&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&dq=Noncommutative+Noetherian+rings&ots=8UtVO6F-wQ&sig=9f4RvubqAdPJboT3B-aqeTJPJ30&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Noncommutative%2520Noetherian%2520rings&f=false) and they allow zero divisors as well. The point is that if $S$ satisfies the Ore's condition (which is nothing but your first condition), then the set {$r\in R, rs=0$ for some $s\in S$} is an ideal in $R$ which is precisely the kernel of the natural map $R\rightarrow RS^{-1}$.

Answer (score 7):

From the apparent lack of complete answers in the literature, I figured I'd write the whole proof of the well-definedness of multiplication since it is only boring, not hard.  I will write the equivalence class of a fraction $as^{-1}$ as $(a,s)$; and the equivalence relation as $\sim$.  I'm assuming that you have full proofs that $\sim$ is a well-defined equivalence relation, and two classes can be brought to a common denominator. (For instance, you can find such proofs in Lam's "Lectures on Modules and Rings".)

Given classes $(a_1,s_1)$ and $(a_2,s_2)$, by the Ore condition we have $s_1 r=a_2s$ for some $r\in R$ and $s\in S$ (where $S$ is the multiplicative set we are inverting).  Then we want to define $(a_1,s_1)*(a_2,s_2)=(a_1r,s_2s)$.

**Claim 1:** This is independent of the choice of $r$ and $s$.

Indeed, suppose we also have $s_1 r'=a_2s'$ for some $r'\in R$ and $s'\in S$.  Since $(a_1r,s_2s)=(a_1rx,s_2sx)$ for any $x\in R$ such that $sx\in S$ (in fact, more generally for any $x\in R$ such that $s_2sx\in S$) from how we defined the equivalence classes, after replacing $s$ and $s'$ by a common denominator, we may as well assume $s'=s$.  Then $s_1r=a_2s=a_2s'=s_1r'$, hence $s_1(r-r')=0$.  By the zero-divisor condition, $(r-r')t=0$ for some $t\in S$.  Thus $(a_1r,s_2s)\sim (a_1rt,s_2st)\sim (a_1r't,s_2s't)\sim (a_1r',s_2s')$.

**Claim 2:** Multiplication is independent of the choice of representative for the class $(a_1,s_1)$.

It suffices to prove this for another representative of this class of the form $(a_1x,s_1x)$ for some $x\in R$ with $s_1x\in S$.  (Why?  Because any two representatives can be brought to a common denominator.)  The Ore condition gives us $(s_1x) r'=a_2s'$ for some $r'\in R$ and $s'\in S$.

By Claim 1, we may as well assume $s=s'$.  Then $s_1xr=a_2s'=a_2s=s_1r$, hence $s_1(r-xr)=0$.  By the argument at the end of claim 1 we are done with claim 2.

**Claim 3:** Multiplication is independent of the choice of representative for the class $(a_2,s_2)$.

Again, it suffices to do this for a representative $(a_2x,s_2x)$ for some $x\in R$ with $s_2x\in S$.  By the Ore condition, write $sr'=xs'$ with $r'\in R$ and $s'\in S$.  (This is a little different than the other uses of the Ore condition.) Then $s_1rr'=a_2sr'=a_2xs'$.

We just need to see that $(a_1r,s_2s)\sim (a_1rr',s_2xs')$.  This is obvious, since if we multiply the first set of reps on the right by $r'$ we get the second set of reps.

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

The following set of notes seems to do what you want.  They are written by M. Artin (and posted on the website of P. Etingof, for a course he taught):

http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/artinnotes.pdf

Comment: Thanks David! Here as well, Artin only construct the ring of fractions for a set S containing only regular elements.
This construction does not work in the general case, when we allow elements in S to be zero-divisors.

Comment: Oops, my apologies!  I think I just have a "Here be dragons" sign over the zero divisors situation in my mind, which resulted in my being blind to that key detail of your post, as a sort of psychological defense mechanism =].  I'll leave this answer up, since it is a nice reference anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Categories and Modules with K-Theory in View (Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics) 
A. J. Berrick , M. E. Keating