# Cohn's localization for rings with enough idempotents

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings, localization

I am in the following situation: I have a non-unitary (associative) ring $R$ with enough idempotents or, if you prefer, a small pre-additive category. Actually, I even know that $R$ is right coherent (in the sense that the category of unitary right $R$ modules is locally coherent, i.e., for unitary right $R$-modules, the class of finitely presented=coherent modules is Abelian), and I am also happy to add some good cohomological properties (e.g., I think that the projective dimension is $\leq 2$).

In this setting, I have a family elements of $R$ or, equivalently, a set of morphisms between finitely generated projective unitary right $R$-modules, that I would like to see as isomorphisms in some universal way. If $R$ was unitary, I could simply take the Cohn's localization and I would be done. So the following question seems natural:

**Question:** Is there a non-unitary analog of Cohn's localization for rings with enough idempotents? Is there any book that I could use a reference?

Comment: Sorry but I am curious: you want to invert arbitrary family of elements of $R$ or family of maps between fgp modules over $R$? I can see how the former implies the latter but fail to see the converse. In the case of former, I think the abstract nonsense argument here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/97558/78431 should apply as well to demonstrate the existence of such localisation.